# Two maximal value in array. Sorted and Array.Sort()

Tags: c#, .net

Compare the two methods of sorting the array in ascending order, where can I optimize? How best to handle exception handling?

```
    class Inside {

    Random rand = new Random();

        // step 1.1: Fill array, output array

        public void SortedArray(int arrSize) {

            int[] arrOne = new int[arrSize];
            Console.Write("Array size: " + arrSize + "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tARRAY\n");

            for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++) {

                arrOne[x] = rand.Next(-1000, 1000);
                Console.Write("{0, 8} | ", arrOne[x]);
                if (x % 8 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // step 1.2: Sorted array and output on monitor two maximal value

            for (int i = 0; i < arrOne.Length; i++) {

                int minIndex = i;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < arrOne.Length; j++) if (arrOne[minIndex] > arrOne[j]) minIndex = j;
                int temp = arrOne[minIndex];
                arrOne[minIndex] = arrOne[i];
                arrOne[i] = temp;
            }

            Console.Write("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tARRAY SORTED\n\n");

            for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++) {
                Console.Write("{0, 8} | ", arrOne[x]);
                if (x % 8 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nMaximal value 1: " + arrOne[arrOne.Length - 1] + "\nMaximal value 2: " + arrOne[arrOne.Length - 2]);
        }

        // Step 2.1: Fill array and output

        public void SortedMethod(int arrSize) {

        int[] arrOne = new int[arrSize];
        Console.Write("Array size: " + arrSize + "\n\t\t\t\t\t\tARRAY\n");

        for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++)  {

            arrOne[x] = rand.Next(-1000, 1000);
            Console.Write("{0, 8} | ", arrOne[x]);
            if (x % 8 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
        }

        // Step 2.2: Sorted array and output on monitor two maximal value

        Array.Sort(arrOne);
        Console.Write("\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tARRAY SORTED\n\n");

        for (int x = 0; x < arrOne.Length; x++)  {
            Console.Write("{0, 8} | ", arrOne[x]);
            if (x % 8 == 0) Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nMaximal value 1: " + arrOne[arrOne.Length - 1] + "\nMaximal value 2: " + arrOne[arrOne.Length - 2]);
    }
}


// user class

class Data {

static void Main() {

        // Step 1: Call the sort method by selecting
        Inside obj = new Inside();
        Console.Write("Please, enter array size: ");
        int sizeArr = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        var timeStart = Stopwatch.StartNew(); 
         obj.SortedArray(sizeArr);
         timeStart.Stop();

        // Step 2: Call method Array.sort()

        var timeStartTwo = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        obj.SortedMethod(sizeArr);
        timeStartTwo.Stop();

        // Step 3: Compare runtime

        Console.Write("SortedArray = {0}\nSortedMethod = {1}", timeStart.Elapsed, timeStartTwo.Elapsed + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should decide first, what you really need to do: is it _sorting_ the array or _finding two greatest items_ in it. Sorting requires \$ O(n\log n) \$ operations in the worst case (and the bubble sort algorithm needs \$ O(n^2) \$) while a linear search for two largest items is just \$O(n)\$.

Comment: What do you want to have handled for exceptions? Sure user input should be handled more carefully, however, I wouldn't call it exception handlng

Comment: @Icepickle Why not ? But what about FormatException ?

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev to be honest I would look more to TryParse methods, I simply don't like catching errors without a concept behind it, especially not when they can be avoided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> for (int j = i + 1; j < arrOne.Length; j++) if (arrOne[minIndex] > arrOne[j]) minIndex = j;
> ```

This is by far the worst line in your code. It took me a while to realize that there is actually an `if` behind the `for` while I was wondering why didn't you indent the three lines below it but wait, these lines are not part of the `for`, it's the `if`. You should *always* use curly brackets

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < arrOne.Length; j++) 
{ 
    if (arrOne[minIndex] > arrOne[j]) 
    {
        minIndex = j;
    }
}
```

This is how it should look like.

Comment: This is obviously a good correction, however I don't think that the user input is handled that good either. I'm sure that could also be added as a correction

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to sort to get the two largest.

Your brace style is the convention in Java. In C#, it is more usual to see an open brace on a new line.

That looks like a [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

Should break the sort out as a method:

```
public static void SelectionSort(int[] a)
{
    int n = a.Length;
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++)
    {
        int iMin = j;
        for (int i = j + 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] < a[iMin])
            {
                iMin = i;
            }
        }
        if (iMin != j)
        {
            int temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[iMin];
            a[iMin] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure you have useful information in here which would benefit greatly from full sentences and some explanation. E.g. Your *brace* style is the convention in Java. In C#, it is more usual to see an open brace on a new line.